# aws/sdk error on deleting object in node js even after AmazonS3FullAccess, correct bucket policy and not blocking any public access

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

Permission given to the user whose access key and secret access key that I am using is AmazonS3FullAccess (Added that user to a group with AmazonS3FullAccess, earlier had tried adding a policy to the user with the permissions too. It didn't work). Tried everything on the net and stack overflow. Nothing is working.

This is the setup of s3 in node js :-

```
require("dotenv").config();
const multer=require("multer");
const path=require("path");
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3')
const fs=require("fs");

const bucketName=process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME;
const region=process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION;
const accessKeyId=process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
const secretAccessKey=process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY

const s3=new S3({
    region,
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey,
    signatureVersion: "v4"
});

function uploadFile(file){
    const fileStream=fs.createReadStream(file.path);

    const uploadParams={
        Bucket:bucketName,
        Body:fileStream,
        Key:file.filename
    }

    return s3.upload(uploadParams).promise();
}

module.exports = {uploadFile, s3, bucketName}
```

```
    const params={
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key:req.body.image
    }

    s3.deleteObject(params, function(err,data){
        if(err){
            throw err
        }
    })
```

This is my bucket policy :-

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1674235426665",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1674235419839",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::secondhandsellit/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the error that shuts down my backend server :-

```
C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at Request.extractError (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\services\s3.js:711:35)
    at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10   
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10   
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rohit\OneDrive\Desktop\code\secondhandsellit\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9) {
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  region: null,
  time: 2023-01-20T17:26:29.116Z,
  requestId: 'GXSSWPSSGXDBEXRJ',
  extendedRequestId: '/KDF6gAGAnevZQ/qh2ttGAyYPJoQ5ePX07rEg0OikBhP+X/sGxUeWS08cWTIJTySipdAgxbcKeM=',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 37.277269050256145
}
```

I tried all the solutions on net and other stack overflow discussions to remove the error on aws/sdk after trying to delete an object from the s3 bucket.

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try following policy configuration. Pretty much there are 2 changes:

- Specifying bucket and its content in `Resource`.
- Specifying IAM user in `Principal`

**NOTE**: Replace part this part `arn:aws:iam::YourAccountID:user/YourUser`. You will be able to find user id in IAM dashboard. Just copy and paste `User ARN` field value.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1674808953577",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1674808949474",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::secondhandsellit",
        "arn:aws:s3:::secondhandsellit/*"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::YourAccountID:user/YourUser"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

FYI: Policy was generated using - https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html